# How can I set a delay in Verilog using a clock?

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, delay

I'm trying to write an always block that will open a valve and then keep it open for a few seconds and then close it if needed. The valve opens when the input is 1 and it closes when it's zero. How can I make the code wait for a few seconds after the valve opens so that it doesn't close right after it opens?

Here is my code:

```
input in, alteraclock;
output reg out;
reg clock;

clock myclock(.clkin(alteraclock), .clkout(clock));

always@(in)
begin

if(in==1)

begin
out=1;  //open valve

end

else
begin
out=0;  //close valve
end

end
```

PS: I'm using an Altera DE2-115, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use a state machine and a large counter.  In one state, wait for the input to change.  When the input changes, set the counter to a large number, update the output, and switch to the delay state.  In the delay state, decrement the counter.  When it reaches zero, switch back to the wait for input state.

Edit: I'm not going to write your code for you, but here is a template for a state machine that you can play with:

```
localparam [1:0]
    STATE_IDLE = 2'd0,
    STATE_1 = 2'd1,
    STATE_2 = 2'd2;

reg [1:0] state_reg = STATE_IDLE, state_next;

reg [16:0] count_reg = 0, count_next;

always @* begin
    state_next = STATE_IDLE;

    count_next = count_reg;

    case (state_reg)
        STATE_IDLE: begin
            // idle state
            if (condition) begin
                count_next = some_value;
                state_next = STATE_1;
            end else begin
                state_next = STATE_IDLE;
            end
        end
        STATE_1: begin
            // some state
            count_next = count_reg - 1;

            if (count_reg == 0) begin
                state_next = STATE_2;
            end else begin
                state_next = STATE_1;
            end
        end
        STATE_2: begin
            // another state
            if (some_condition) begin
                state_next = STATE_IDLE;
            end else begin
                state_next = STATE_2;
            end
        end
    endcase
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        state_reg <= STATE_IDLE;
        count_reg <= 0;
    end else begin
        state_reg <= state_next;
        count_reg <= count_next;
    end
end
```

Here is a way to do this without an explicit state machine:

```
reg [32:0] counter = 0;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        counter <= 0;
        out <= 0;
    end else if (counter > 0) begin
        counter <= counter - 1;
    end else begin
        out <= in;
        if (out != in) begin
            counter <= some_delay_value;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Mind helping me with the code?

Comment: I think this is way too complicated for what I want to do.

Comment: What, a two always block state machine is too complicated?  It is possible to compress it into a single always block, but it's slightly less readable.  Also, the template I posted has 3 states; you only need 2.

Comment: Well, I suppose with only two states, you don't really need a whole state machine.

Comment: What is that rst in the first if condition?

Comment: rst is short for reset

Comment: I know, but where is it initialized/used?

Comment: it would be sourced from an external reset source (i.e. reset button) and/or a reset synchronizer.  You want to make sure sequential circuits get reset into a known initial state on power up.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use a counter.

Most likely, you'll have a clock of 50Mhz which means you if you count to 50 million starting from 0 on your counter, it will take that clock around 1s. So you can output 1'b1 from your counter's module, once it's done counting. Hence, the output of this counter's module can give you a slowed down clk.

Implement it as explained above.